# Better way to return the value from a function

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

char* my_strcpy(char* source, char* destination) {
    char* p = destination;
    while( *source != '\0' ) {
        *p++ = *source++;
    }
    *p = '\0';
    return destination;
}

int main() {
    char stringa[40] = "Time and tide wait for none";
    char stringb[40];
    char *ptr;
    char *ptr1;

    ptr = stringa;
    ptr1 = stringb;

    puts(stringa);
    puts(ptr);

    my_strcpy(ptr, ptr1);
    puts(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Here the variable `destination`, as the local copy of the function, is returning the pointer is safe. I believe it will be safe as long as the address is used immediately after returning or else what if some other process uses the address, it will be changed.
How to return safely without doing `return destination`?

Is it possible to do a malloc for `p` and return it rather than assigning the location pointed by `destination`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity are you practicing array copying and using pointers? Isn't it easier to do `strcpy(destination, source);`? Also no need to return the pointer as you're not using it anyway :)

Comment: "what if some other process uses the address" in most operating systems, address space is virtualized, therefore you do not have to worry about this

Comment: Didn't you mean `*p = '\0';` instead of `p='\0';`

Comment: yeah u r right LS_dev

Comment: Instead of just returning the dest address, you could perhaps return the number of characters copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`destination` isn't controlled by `my_strcpy`, so what happens to it outside of the function is irrelevant to `my_strcpy`.  That is to say, it's perfectly safe and expected for the function to return `destination`.  Whoever called `my_strcpy` will be responsible to make sure the variable's memory is ok.  Returning the `destination` variable is simply a convenience for function chaining.

You could malloc and return a new area of memory (though then you wouldn't need a `destination` parameter).  This is basically the functionality of `strdup`, and it's the responsibility of the caller of `strdup` to free the memory that was allocated.

Note, there's no risk of another process corrupting the memory.  Unless you're dealing with shared memory, processes each have access to only their memory.  Some function later on in this process could change what you did in `my_strcpy`, but that's not the problem of `my_strcpy`.  As for it being safe if it's used immediately after the function, you're copying into space that was assigned to you.  The `p` value isn't the memory you're writing into; it's just the pointer to the memory.  And the memory itself isn't on the stack.  As jpw mentioned at some point - you don't need the `p` variable at all.

Comment: Yes you are right. It points to the address location of stringb.